# Why are parentheses needed in this TikZ calculation?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am creating a multi-page PDF with TikZ that will be used for an animation. While doing so, I get this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
```

Here is a minimal working example (MWE) that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\def\timesteps{10}                                                                                                                        
\foreach \timestep in {0,1,...,\timesteps} {
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \path[draw] (0, 0) circle (1);

    \def\initialx{-1};
    \def\initialy{0};
    \def\finalx{0.9};
    \def\finaly{0};
    \def\length{0.1};

    \def\xi{{\initialx+(\finalx-\initialx)*(\timestep/\timesteps)}};
    \def\yi{{\initialy+(\finaly-\initialy)*(\timestep/\timesteps)}};

    \def\xf{{\initialx+(\finalx-\initialx)*(\timestep/\timesteps)+\length}}; % This line works ...                                        
    %\def\xf{{\xi+\length}}; % ... but this line does not ...                                                                             
    %\def\xf{{(\xi)+\length}}; % ... unless there are parentheses                                                                         
    \def\yf{{\yi}};

    \path[draw, ->] (\xi, \yi) -- (\xf, \yf);

  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Running the MWE produces the desired output: a simple 11 page PDF of an arrow moving across the screen. Now, I comment out the line

```
\def\xf{{\initialx+(\finalx-\initialx)*(\timestep/\timesteps)+\length}};
```

and uncomment the line

```
\def\xf{{\xi+\length}};
```

because they are mathematically equivalent. I get the previously mentioned error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
```

I googled this in relation to TikZ, and all the answers say that curly braces are needed around a calculation. However, that line above has curly braces, so I do not think that is the problem. After trying different things, I noticed that parentheses around `\xi` solved the problem:

```
\def\xf{{(\xi)+\length}};
```

Therefore, my question is why are parentheses needed here? As I mentioned before, I thought if a calculation is inside curly braces, nothing else special is necessary. Is there any "official" documentation that discusses this? Finally, I am new to TikZ, so feel free to improve my code.

Comment: I'm surprise it works at all.  Remove the extra layer of `{}` around the macro contents.

Comment: As @HenriMenke said, replace all `{{` and `}}` by `{` and `}`, and remove the `;` at the end of `\def`, they are not needed (but get gobbled inside the `tikzpicture`). However, you should use `\path[draw, ->] ({\xi}, {\yi}) -- ({\xf},{\yf});`, then it works regardless of whether you add these `(...)`. You might also want to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\def`, then the expressions would be parsed and again no problem.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The `;` actually does not get gobbled, so you might end up with messages like `Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!` in your log.

Comment: @HenriMenke Well, what I meant to say is that it does not show up in the picture. Whether or not "gobbled" is the 100% correct term one may discuss, but it is certainly the case that the `;` are to be removed, as I said. Do you agree?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Of course, the `;` should be removed.

Comment: Don't discuss about things that can not help the OP. He made a clear question: can we help him or not?